# Use Tasker to disable WiFi if not connected

Tags: wifi, tasker

I want to use Tasker to turn WiFi OFF IF it is not connected to my home network. How can I do that with a variable? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you need to use variable for that? This can be easily achieved without variables.

## step 1

set a profile with a `State` -> `Net` -> `Wifi connected`

in a task add action `set variable` name it `wifiConnected` and set it to "yes" or "true" or whatever you want, but keep in mind that variable name must contain at least one capital letter, to be public (be visible in all tasks)

## step 2

set a second profile with a `State` -> `Net` -> `Wifi connected` but this time select option `invert` (so the profile will become active, when wifi disconnected)

in a task use `set variable` and set it's value to "no" or "false" or whatever you want

## step 3

create profile with a `state` -> `variables` -> `variable value`

in the left field type in variable name `wifiConnected`

in the right one type "no" or "false" or whatever you set it to on disconnecting

as a task for this profile use `net` -> `WiFi` -> `Off`

that's about it.

I'd really suggest you on reading some more about Tasker and how it works, as such things are *the* very basics

//edit

to do the same without setting variable, just do a profile from step 2, but instead of setting variable, use task from step 3, to disable wifi

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I think what you wrote above does what it's supposed to do only the first time, then it needs something to trigger it automatically like a builtin variable or so...in my opinion that doesn't work as intended...no offence :)
Well, you will need something that will trigger the task for the first time, it's about the task that verifies what's the wificonnected's value. If it is "no", that means you don't have any SSIDs to connect to.You will add a wait task, let's say 2 minutes and net-wifi-off, because you will want to disable wifi if, after a specific period of time when your phone wasn't able to connect to any network.
But, you will want something continuous, in loop so you will have to add a task/goto action, like this!
Let's say you have this action:
A1: task/wait-2 minutes
A2: if %wifiConnected ~no then set WIFI off
goto A2
This way you'll phone will scan for %wifiConnected's value, continuously. As an alternative, you may cancel that loop once your wifi has already set to off because you don't need that value anymore.
I mean, your screen on-> task activated->elapsed 2 minutes-> no ssids to connect to-> wifi off
Then, you manually or not necessarly turn your wifi back on, but the task won't be triggered anymore because the screen is already on, this is why you will have to use that goto action :)
Or, you could go and disable/enable tasker such that your task( that checks for wifiConnected's value) being triggered again :)...hope that helped...my profile works like smooth :)